# Is the image of a subspace a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'll clarify this question a bit. Let $f: E \rightarrow F$ be a linear map between these two vector spaces. Let $H1 \subset E$.

Now, I know that $Im(E) \subset F$. But is $Im(H1) \subset F$ true? My initial assumption is that this isn't always true, since, for example:

$f: R \rightarrow R-{0}$ ;  $x \mapsto x-2x$. Now the image of the subsapce which contains every $2x$ isn't a subspace since it would be equal to $0$, and therefore isn't defined in $R-0$.

Assuming this is correct (correct me if I got something wrong, please!), then in what cases would the image of $H1$ be a subspace of $F$? When it's bijective, for example?

Comment: Don't you have that $Im(H1) \subset Im(E)$?

Comment: Yes, the image of a subspace under a linear map is again a subspace. (Proof: if $u$ and $v$ are in the image, then $u=f(a)$ and $v=f(b)$ for some $a, b$, so $u+v=f(a)+f(b)=f(a+b)$ is in the image too. Same story with scalar multiplication.) Your question has lots of issues. For one thing, do you mean $f(x)=-x$ on the reals? For another thing, $R-0$ is *not a vector space*. And what does “the subspace which contains every $2x$” mean?

Comment: @BrunoTassone Ah, yeah, man that was very obvious, thanks.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I think I've thought about it in the wrong way, thanks for the simple proof.

Comment: What vector space structure are you putting on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that the map you give from $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus 0 $ by
$$
x \mapsto x - 2x
$$
Doesn't actually map to $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0 $ since $f(0) = 0 \not\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ (note also that $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ does not form a vector space under addition). In the general case, yes you can always restrict the domain of a linear transformation from vector spaces, and the image of the restriction will always be a subspace of the target space. Further given a linear transformation $f:V\to W$ with $V$ and $W$ being vector spaces, if $S$ is a subspace of $V$, then the image of $S$ is a subspace of the image of $V$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't realize I had such a dumb mistake. Alright, good to know!

Comment: @agaminon Sometimes it's hard to spot the obvious things when one has spent a long time on something :)